# Is there any way to refocus a question in the question list?

Tags: support, acceptable-question, asking-questions, acceptable-answer, answers

I have a two related questions:

1. If a question goes for a long time unanswered, what can we do to get more attention brought to it?
2. If it goes on for too long unanswered, can we republish the question again?

Comment: Editing the question bumps it up the front page. But editing solely for the purpose of bumping up is frowned upon. When you have a bit more rep, you can also set a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preferred mechanism for this is the [Bounty](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). Once you have enough rep you can set a bounty on your question (or other people's questions.)

This highlights the question, and generates interest.

Publishing the question again is definitely frowned upon - this will get closed very quickly, and will likely get you down votes.

As @paj28 commented, editing a question does bump it up, but you need a reason for editing - you must improve it, add some additional useful information etc., not just edit it bump it.

That said, you don't currently have any questions that are old - your oldest one is only 4 days old, so I wouldn't be thinking about this yet.